# Heroku PHP MSSQL Extesion/ SQL_SRV

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel, heroku, lumen

How can I add a `sql_srv.so` extension on Heroku?
Im losing hope now,

There are no extention on this, also Asure is not free,
All I need is its driver to work with a third party database,
How can I achieve it?

Or are there any link to read on how to add custom php extension on its php.ini?

Im using Laravel Lumen 7.2.1
PHP Version is 7.3^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Heroku doesn't support SQL Server extension. from [official website](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support) PHP 7.3 on heroku only support below SQL extension:

- MySQL (PDO) (uses mysqlnd)
- MySQLi (uses mysqlnd)
- PostgreSQL
- PostgreSQL (PDO)

from github [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/175) they said:

> We currently have no plans to support that. mssql is no longer
> available in PHP 7, so there is only ODBC left as an option, and
> that's a bit of a nightmare to set up on Linux.

and the latest [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/417):

> There are two reasons why this hasn't happened yet:
>
> - we need the underlying ODBC driver libraries and in fact the entire
>   ODBC ecosystem on all stacks first (and 20.04 isn't supported yet by
>   Microsoft, but we have that in internal beta already);
> - https://odbceula.blob.core.windows.net/eula17/LICENSE17.TXT needs to
>   be looked at by lawyers, and that takes time, as you might expect.

Comment: So I guess, AWS is the solution, Thanks Man!